# Relationship between exponent and logarithm

Tags: logarithms

How is the property $b^{x+y} = b^x\cdot b^y$ related to the property $\log_b(xy) = \log_b(x)+\log_b(y)$?

Comment: By means of the fact that, when books prove the latter, they write the former, then a "thus", and finally the latter.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Review your definition/properties of the logarithm. You should be able to *prove* the relation between these statements.

Answer (score 1):

Very strongly.

**Hint:** Write $A:=b^x$ and $B:=b^y$.